# Por que motivo se passou a usar muito a palavra Summit em português?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, tradução-inglês, estrangeirismos

Por que motivo se passou a usar muito a palavra “summit”? Não  encontro a tradução para esta palavra.
É uma abreviatura?
Exemplo: Oceanos Summit 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A palavra "summit" tem origem inglesa e [pode ser traduzida como](https://www.influx.com.br/blog/o-que-significa-summit-em-ingles/) "cimeira" (no sentido de encontro/assembleia), ou como "cume"/"topo"/"cúpula"/"ápice" (com o significado de ponto máximo).

No entanto, a recente popularização da palavra "summit" deve-se ao uso frequente do termo para nomear um tipo específico de conferências/encontros internacionais. A palavra começou por ser utilizada neste contexto para designar encontros políticos internacionais - que, em português, são conhecidos como "cimeiras". No entanto, na língua inglesa, o significado de "summit" como encontro internacional tem-se tornado mais abrangente, englobando um conjunto de eventos, semelhantes a conferências, que, em português, não se enquadram na categoria "cimeira".

Deixo aqui uma citação de um artigo online que discute este assunto com algum pormenor: [Summit vs Conference: What’s the Difference?](https://www.hubilo.com/blog/summit-vs-conference)

> Ao contrário das conferências on-line, projetadas para incentivar a participação do público, as "summits" virtuais exigem que o público preste atenção total e ouça os palestrantes. (...) As "summits" tendem a ser direcionadas a pessoas de grande importância que são influentes em seu setor, por exemplo, cirurgiões, representantes do governo e executivos de empresas.

Assim, o uso de "summit", neste contexto, significa um encontro internacional que reúne aquilo que é considerado o "topo"/"cume" num dado setor - nomeadamente, pessoas e empresas especializadas que tenham um impacte considerável no desenvolvimento de uma área específica. Em Português, não existe uma palavra equivalente a "summit" que permita distinguir esse tipo de eventos de uma conferência, daí a importação do estrangeirismo.

A popularização desta palavra, no contexto específico de Portugal, pode até ser atribuída ao facto de a [Web Summit](https://websummit.com/) (considerada a maior conferência internacional tecnológica do mundo) [se ter deslocado para Lisboa em 2016](https://www.publico.pt/2015/09/23/tecnologia/noticia/lisboa-vai-acolher-um-dos-maiores-eventos-de-tecnologia-da-europa-1708710), levando a que a palavra "summit" passasse a ser mais conhecida em Portugal, e utilizada na nomeação de outros eventos de natureza semelhante.

Answer (score 1):

Summit tem uma tradução direta que é: cume, como o cume de uma montanha.

Também é usada em encontro, quando é um encontro de entidades de topo, neste sentido é melhor traduzido como "cúpula", algo que fica sobre.

Weather summit, neste caso, poderia ser traduzido como "Cúpula do Clima".

O uso se tornou comum mais recentemente devido ao internacionalismo de forma geral, pois congressos e eventos estão cada vez mais acessíveis através de todo o globo, seja de forma presencial ou remota. Desta forma, como inglês é usado na maioria dos casos como lingua franca internacional -- por razões que são maiores do que uma resposta no SE -- encontramos o uso da palavra de forma cada vez mais frequente.

Na minha humilde opinião, usa-se estes anglicismos por que temos pouca estima pela nossa própria língua e necessitamos de reconhecimento estrangeiro.

Comment: Olá Lin, na verdade há diversas razões para se usar expressões de outras línguas — a que você menciona é apenas uma delas, e duvido que a mais comum: hábito de misturar línguas; convicção da superioridade do termo estrangeiro (específico, não da totalidade da língua); preguiça e/ou desatenção; comportamento de rebanho; entre outras, são apenas algumas das possibilidades. Penso que seu comentário não contribui para sua resposta, que é boa, embora parcial, pelo contrário, apenas distrai. Note também que a pergunta central (razão do suposto aumento da frequência de uso) não foi respondida.

Comment: Pode desenvolver mais?

Comment: Esta noção de que o uso de anglicismos/estrangeirismos vem de complexos de inferioridade, preguiça ou desatenção, para além de  subjetiva, não me parece ter fundamento. Vivemos numa sociedade global. A popularidade do inglês em detrimento de outras línguas é uma consequência direta dessa globalização e da posição dos EUA no plano socioeconomico global. Aliado ao facto de que o inglês é a língua com vocabulário mais extenso, esta importação de termos é apenas um fenómeno natural de evolução linguística

Comment: Ingles como lingua de vocabulário mais extenso? Falta citação aqui. E com relacao ao estrangeirismo é, como disse, humilde opinião.

Usar palavras estrangeiras, dentro de contextos locais, e não globais, para definir coisas que já estão definidas na lingua é sim complexo de inferioridade socio-cultural. Por exemplo quando alguem em uma reunião refere-se ao quadro branco como "whiteboard", ou chama de "banner" o galhardete que sustenta papeis. Isso é MUITO diferente de quando importamos palavras que não existiam antes dentro de um novo contexto como "twittar".

Comment: Não sei como fuciona em Portugal, mas aqui, em Terras Brasilis, as coisas chegam a ser engraçadas. Usam termos como "vamos shiftar a reunião", onde poderiam dizer simplesmente: a) "vamos remarcar a reunião"; ou b) "vamos postergar a reunião"; ou c) "vamos adiantar a reunião", à depender do contexto. As marcas e produtos escritas em inglês, normalmente tem mais apelo comercial, dão aparência de mais importantes. Se isso não é vira-latismo cultural, não sei o que é. E não quero dizer que as pessoas que o fazem tem qualquer culpa, mas sim, que é um produto do imperialismo cultural estadunidense.

Comment: @Lin Segundo o Oxford Dictionary, a língua inglesa possui mais de 200.000 palavras, tornando-a a língua com vocabulário mais extenso. Outras línguas conseguem ultrapassar este valor apenas se contarmos, por exemplo, as muitas contrações do mesmo verbo que existem nas línguas românticas, algo que o Oxford Dictionary descarta porque não contribuem para significar "mais" vocabulário

Comment: Relativamente ao resto, eu concordo consigo! O uso excessivo de estrangeirismos é de facto um produto do imperialismo cultural e económico dos EUA, mas ao usar expressões como "complexo de inferioridade"/"preguiça" estamos a pôr o ónus e a culpa na população. Este tipo de discurso tira atenção e remove a "culpa" do verdadeiro problema (que se estende muito além das questões linguísticas) que constitui o entranhar da cultura dos EUA em vários aspetos das nossas vidas (na língua, na economia, na cultura artística, e até na política), devido, sim, ao imperialismo e à globalização

Comment: Contudo, não podemos dizer que isto não é natural: ao longo da história da humanidade, sempre que um país se torna uma superpotência, existe uma imposição/entranhar da cultura desse país nos países que lhe são "inferiores" no plano económico. O colonialismo europeu é se calhar o melhor exemplo disso, mas mesmo dentro da própria Europa, houve uma altura em que a "moda" era importar palavras do francês, particularmente quando França se tornou o centro do Iluminismo e isso contribuiu para a evolução das línguas

Comment: Agora, estamos a testemunhar o mesmo, porque os países anglo-saxónicos ocupam o centro do plano sociocultural. Podemos achar que isso é mais ou menos correto, ou que pode existir um certo comportamento de rebanho quando adotamos essas palavras... mas não é nada de novo e não deixa de ser uma forma natural de evoluir as línguas